# Kibana error /usr/local/bin/node: bad option: --no-warnings

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I just downloaded ElasticSearch and was trying to start Kibana. However I cannot make it.

I am working with 5.2.2 versions of both programs ([ElasticSearch 5.2.2](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/archive/v5.2.2.tar.gz)
and [Kibana 5.2.2](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/archive/v5.2.2.tar.gz)). Once I initiated ElasticSearch (I assume it is working properly since it responds to a `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200` request), I try to start Kibana but the following error appears:

```
$ ./kibana
/usr/local/bin/node: bad option: --no-warnings
```

I am working in OSX. Furthermore, I have previously modified the file config/kibana.yml to point to the default `elasticsearch.url`.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

EDIT: I inspected the kibana script and the following line is raising the error:

```
exec "${NODE}" $NODE_OPTIONS --no-warnings "${DIR}/src/cli" ${@}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of node are you running? (`node --version` or `node -v`). If it is less than version `6.x`, then that cli flag is not supported.

> --no-warnings
>
> Added in: v6.0.0 Silence all process warnings (including
>   deprecations).

https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_no_warnings

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I am running v7.7.3. I do not know what was wrong before to be honest, but now it is working. Only difference is I used [ElasticSearch 5.2.2](https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5.2.2.zip) and [Kibana 5.2.2](https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana/kibana-5.2.2-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz) links instead

Comment: Oh, well it depends what version of `node` the kibana script is actually using. I'd recommend adding an `echo $NODE` to the shell script and then trying it again. https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/bin/kibana#L17